# Is there a way to make HTML text flow around images - regarding transparency?

Tags: html, css, layout, text

On an HTML page, you can make text flow around images with the CSS property "float". But this will only consider the image's rectangle, not transparent regions in the image. I now have an image that has large areas of full transparency, like for example a circular logo, and would like the text to flow around the circle contour of that logo, not the bounding rectangle. At least on the text-facing side of the image.

I know that CSS is probably not suitable for that task. But is there some workaround, like hidden divs or something that can achieve the same (or a similar) effect? Has somebody already seen such a thing?

Comment: You might try out [The Box Office](http://www.theboxoffice.be/index.php) and if it doesn't do exactly what you were looking for you might at least be able to adapt the techniques there.

Comment: Related video: http://blogs.adobe.com/designandweb/2010/10/improving-the-web-for-digital-publishing.html Can't wait to see mainstream browser engines do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a PHP function for that now. It takes the PNG image and generates the <div> elements to make the text flow around another form than the image's rectangle. You can find the code here:

https://unclassified.software/source/shaped-image-flow

**Update 2020/2021:**

Now there is a CSS property for that: [shape-outside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside). It can be given an image with transparency that will determine the outside shape to let the text flow around. If the visible image is already a PNG, the same image can be used for this CSS property. Additional margin can be added with [shape-margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-margin). Both are supported by anything except IE.

Example:

```html
<img src="img/shape.png" style="shape-outside: url(img/shape.png); shape-margin: 1.5em;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt you can do that easily without making a big mess, of tags, JavaScript or both. One way i can think is placing image on larger zindex and positioning div or divs behind it, and text would flow around them. It would be easiest to use smaller rectangle that excludes transparent areas. But then why not just crop/clip the image? Or you can try floating line height divs behind it, but I guess that it will get quite ugly pretty fast. Or you could try placing each line of text in span/div and positioning them manually or with js by calculating approximate shapes to those that are in the image. One other idea, of which I'm not sure: it *might* be possible do this using svg. But quick search does not show much promise ether.

Any way one more thing to consider, when doing something as experimental and complicated as this, in whatever way you do this, it will most likely be huge pain to make it work well across most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a css property that do just what you want
shape-outside include values of shapes you can use.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-wrap-the-text-around-an-image-using-html-and-css/

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. While the page you linked does not answer the question, it can be made so. And I actually found that out last year. So I've updated my accepted answer to reflect the new possibilities.

Comment: Great. glad that it helpt